# Inequality involving modulus

Tags: inequality

If $\vert x\vert\leqslant a$ and $\vert y\vert\leqslant b$ can we create some inequality that contains $\vert\vert x\vert-\vert y\vert\vert$?

Answer (score 1):

You can write

$$
||x|-|y|| \le \frac{|a+b|+|a-b|}{2}
$$

Answer (score 0):

For example:
$\vert\vert x\vert-\vert y\vert\vert \leq max(a,b)$

Since we can assume that one variable is equal to 0 and the second one equals $max(a,b)$, there's nothing better that we can get.